# Sprite em SVG para o Internet explorer

Tags: html5, css3, svg

Li um artigo que explicava como colocar várias imagens SVG em um único arquivo. O arquivo final ficava dessa forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="imagemA" viewBox="0 0 65.1 36.7">
    <...>
</g>
<g id="imagemB" viewBox="0 0 65.1 36.7">
    <...>
</g>
```

e as imagens eram referenciadas no HTML da seguinte forma:

```
<img src="imagens.svg#imagemA"/>
<img src="imagens.svg#imagemB"/>
```

Porém isso não funciona no nosso querido Internet Explorer.

Qual a melhor forma para criar um sprite de SVGs que funcione em todos os navegadores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que não é exatamente a "melhor" forma. Mas tb não conheço outra rss. Essa é apenas uma opção que as vezes pode te ajudar em algum momento. ***E funciona no IE!***

A ideia aqui é colocar todas as figuras dentro de um só SVG na forma de `symbols`, e colocar um `ID` para cada um desses `symbols`. Depois vc usa o `<use>` para chamar esses `ID` pelo `href=""` (xlink:href é para funcionar no Safari tb).

O inconveniente dessa técnica é que a tag `<svg>` com todos os `symbols` precisa estar dentro do seu arquivo... não tem como chamar um `.svg` e usar os IDs. É como se vc estivesse chamando apenas uma "partes" de um só SVG com que contém vários outros "svgs" dentro dele. A vantagem é que vc não precisa ficar repetindo o svg inteiro a cada vez que vc repete uma figura. Além disso, ele já está dentro do seu documento e não vai precisar de requisição no servidor.

Como falei não é bem um *spreit*, seria mais um *sprite-indoor* dentro do próprio documento.

```css
svg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg><use xlink:href="#app" href="#app"></use></svg>
<svg><use xlink:href="#face" href="#face"></use></svg>
<svg><use xlink:href="#you" href="#you"></use></svg>
<!-- links que invocam os simbolos -->


<!-- svg com todos os simbolos dentro -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <symbol id="app" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" >
        <g>
            <path  d="M256.064,0h-0.128C114.784,0,0,114.816,0,256c0,56,18.048,107.904,48.736,150.048l-31.904,95.104l98.4-31.456
                C155.712,496.512,204,512,256.064,512C397.216,512,512,397.152,512,256S397.216,0,256.064,0z M405.024,361.504
                c-6.176,17.44-30.688,31.904-50.24,36.128c-13.376,2.848-30.848,5.12-89.664-19.264C189.888,347.2,141.44,270.752,137.664,265.792
                c-3.616-4.96-30.4-40.48-30.4-77.216s18.656-54.624,26.176-62.304c6.176-6.304,16.384-9.184,26.176-9.184
                c3.168,0,6.016,0.16,8.576,0.288c7.52,0.32,11.296,0.768,16.256,12.64c6.176,14.88,21.216,51.616,23.008,55.392
                c1.824,3.776,3.648,8.896,1.088,13.856c-2.4,5.12-4.512,7.392-8.288,11.744c-3.776,4.352-7.36,7.68-11.136,12.352
                c-3.456,4.064-7.36,8.416-3.008,15.936c4.352,7.36,19.392,31.904,41.536,51.616c28.576,25.44,51.744,33.568,60.032,37.024
                c6.176,2.56,13.536,1.952,18.048-2.848c5.728-6.176,12.8-16.416,20-26.496c5.12-7.232,11.584-8.128,18.368-5.568
                c6.912,2.4,43.488,20.48,51.008,24.224c7.52,3.776,12.48,5.568,14.304,8.736C411.2,329.152,411.2,344.032,405.024,361.504z"/>
        </g>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="face" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" >
        <g>
            <path d="M448,0H64C28.704,0,0,28.704,0,64v384c0,35.296,28.704,64,64,64h192V336h-64v-80h64v-64c0-53.024,42.976-96,96-96h64v80
            h-32c-17.664,0-32-1.664-32,16v64h80l-32,80h-48v176h96c35.296,0,64-28.704,64-64V64C512,28.704,483.296,0,448,0z"/>    
        </g>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="you" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" >
        <g>
            <path d="M490.24,113.92c-13.888-24.704-28.96-29.248-59.648-30.976C399.936,80.864,322.848,80,256.064,80
                c-66.912,0-144.032,0.864-174.656,2.912c-30.624,1.76-45.728,6.272-59.744,31.008C7.36,138.592,0,181.088,0,255.904
                C0,255.968,0,256,0,256c0,0.064,0,0.096,0,0.096v0.064c0,74.496,7.36,117.312,21.664,141.728
                c14.016,24.704,29.088,29.184,59.712,31.264C112.032,430.944,189.152,432,256.064,432c66.784,0,143.872-1.056,174.56-2.816
                c30.688-2.08,45.76-6.56,59.648-31.264C504.704,373.504,512,330.688,512,256.192c0,0,0-0.096,0-0.16c0,0,0-0.064,0-0.096
                C512,181.088,504.704,138.592,490.24,113.92z M192,352V160l160,96L192,352z"/>
        </g>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Essa é uma ótima solução, porém eu gostaria que fosse carregado a partir de um arquivo externo. tenho quase 30 logos em SVG, e nem todas serão usadas em todas as páginas. Não vejo como uma boa prática retornar todas as imagens sempre

Comment: @Pilati nesse caso não é o indicado mesmo não. Vc tem que avaliar se o público pra qual se destina o projeto realmente usa o IE para acessar. Caso o IE não seja usado por quem vai usar o sistema pense se não vale a pena continuar com a opção que vc já tem. O fato é que importando um arquivo externo imagem.svg as suas opções para customiza-lo ficam bem limitadas, quando vc chama uma imagem.svg pelo src="" nem a cor dela vc consegue mudar... Talvez com JS e trabalhando no viewBox vc consiga esse sprite com um arquivo .svg que é indexado no documento

Comment: É possivel fazer um sprite em SVG da forma como é feita em arquivos JPG ou PNG? Tipo, colocar varias imagens em posições diferentes e setar a posição e tamanho por meio de CSS pela propriedade `background-image`

Comment: @Pilati É possível sim, eu só não sei a melhor forma de fazer, pois vc precisa mudar os valores do ViewBox. O viewbox tem 4 valores, tipo viewBox="0 0 512 512" os dois últimos valores são tipo o tamanho do "canvas" (como uma janela onde só se vc o que está enquadrado nela), porém o conteúdo que está dentro desse "canvas" pode ser muito maior que o que está visível na tela. Assim trabalhando os dois primeiros valores do viewBox="X Y 0 0" vc contro o eixo X / Y do conteúdo que está dentro do "canvas" mostrando apenas a parte que te interessa, como no Sprit tradicional.

Comment: @Pilati porém isso tb tem limitações pq vc não consegue mudar os valores do viewbox depois que indexou a imagem.svg no documento. Vc só consegue muda-lo direto dentro do arquivo .svg ou se vc colocar o svg inline dentro do documento. Se quiser e for do seu interesse cria uma Nova Pergunta sobre isso que posso te passar uns detalhes.

Comment: Pergunta criada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313390/sprite-em-svg-usando-o-background-image